# How can I control my tablet from my PC, while using it as a second monitor?

Tags: remote-control

I have a not-so-powerful computer, and sometimes, when I'm running games, tabbing out is bothersome. I managed to connect my android tablet as a second monitor for Windows, however I'd like to shift workload even more, by using the Android OS, and not just streaming Windows's stuff to the device.

Basically, I'd like something like this:
I'm playing a game, I decide I want to lookup something on chrome, move mouse to the left/right, it appears on my tablet, I open the chrome app, and google what I was looking for.

Is this possible, and if yes, what apps do I need?